# How to clear value from child input component ? Angular

Tags: angular

I need to clear input value from child component.
I have dynamic add input and on every next input i see previous added data...I need to clear it..

I am try with ViewChild with:

```
<app-child-component #clear></app-child-component>

@ViewChild('clear') myDiv!: ElementRef;
```

but

when i console.log(this.mydiv) i don't see   nativeElement.value like a this question:

[How can I select an element in a component template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/how-can-i-select-an-element-in-a-component-template)

Example of my console.log is different.... I see:

```
cdr: ViewRef {_lView: LComponentView_NewPhoneNumberComponent(146), _cdRefInjectingView: LComponentView_NewPhoneNumberComponent(146), _appRef: null, _attachedToViewContainer: false}
control: FormControl {_hasOwnPendingAsyncValidator: false, _parent: null, pristine: true, touched: false, _onCollectionChange: ƒ, …}
currentRegionCode: "US"
disabled: false
id: "number-phone-input"
onChange: (newValue) => {…}
onTouched: () => {…}
placeholder: "Phone Number"
__ngContext__: LComponentView_AddContactAccountComponent(359) [add-contact, TView, 147, LComponentView_ViewDetailComponent(410), null, null, TNode, LCleanup(41), AddContactAccountComponent, {…}, AnimationRendererFactory, BaseAnimationRenderer, null, LContainer(10), LComponentView_NewPhoneNumberComponent(146), LComponentView_ViewDetailComponent(410), LComponentView_AddContactAccountComponent(359), null, 0, LQueries_, div.container.customer-input-row, form.row.ng-untouched.ng-invalid.ng-dirty, div.col-lg-2.col-md-2.col-sm-2, label.customer-title, text, span.text-danger, text, input.form-control.customer-input-field.ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-invalid, LContainer(10), LContainer(10), div.col-lg-1.col-md-1.col-sm-2.pl-1, label.customer-title, text, span.text-danger, text, input.form-control.customer-input-field.ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-invalid, LContainer(10), LContainer(10), div.col-lg-1.col-md-1.col-sm-2.pl-1, label.customer-title, text, span.text-danger, text, input.form-control.customer-input-field.ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-invalid, LContainer(10), LContainer(10), div.col-lg-2.col-md-.col-sm-2.pl-1, label.customer-title, text, span.text-danger, text, input.form-control.customer-input-field.ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-invalid, LContainer(10), LContainer(10), div.col-lg-4.col-md-4.col-sm-4, div.row, div.col-12, div.form-row, div.form-group.col-12, label, text, span.text-danger, text, LComponentView_NewPhoneNumberComponent(146), NewPhoneNumberComponent, div.col-lg-1.col-md-1.col-sm-2.pl-1.d-flex.align-items-center, div.icon-div, button#submit-contact-button, i.fas.fa-check-circle.check-icon.cursor-disabled, i.fas.fa-times-circle.cancel-icon, FormGroup, {…}, false, undefined, {…}, false, undefined, {…}, false, undefined, {…}, false, undefined, true, {…}, false, {…}, false, {…}, false, {…}, false, {…}, true, {…}, -2146694656, 512, 0, 0, 0, …]
__proto__: Object
```

This values....
What ever i need to clear or destory or what ever to clear input data.....

Answer (score -1):

You have to put it in an appropriate hook, and its:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.myDiv);
}
```

or you can add

```
@ViewChild('clear', {static: true}) myDiv!: ElementRef;
```

and you can use it in other hooks as well

Comment: No, this is not okay. It doesn't help me. The problem here is probably some deep nesting or i don't know what..

Comment: Create a reproducible scenario in stackblitz or similar, because from your question nobody can know what is happening in your nested components...my friend...